# How to make bootstrap distribution in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the bootstrap distribution of an estimated slope in R using the `boot` function. I have made a function which calculates the slope and it's standard error. Now I need to generate a bootstrap distribution and then append this distribution with the slope of my line into a vector. Here is my sample data

```
# rm(list=ls())
set.seed(999123)
x = c(1,1.5,2,3,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6.5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
y = c(21.9,27.8,42.8,48.0,52.5,52.0,53.1,46.1,42.0,39.9,38.1,34.0,33.8,30.0,26.1,24.0,20.0,11.1,6.3)

data = data.frame(x=x, y=y)
```

this is the code I used to build the function to give me the slope of the line and std. error

```
b1=function(data,index){
  x=data$x[index]
  y=data$y[index]
  lmout=lm(y~x)
  b1=coef(lmout)[2]
  return(b1)}

library(boot)
data=data.frame(x=x,y=y)

Nboot = 20
mybdone = boot(data,b1,R=Nboot)
mybdone
```

Does anyone know how to make a bootstrap distribution that I can use to eventually get the bootstrap distribution of the estimated slope?

Comment: Try `coef(lmout)` instead of `coef(lmout)[2]`.

Comment: sorry @jay.sf, I don't think my question was very clear because this answer doesn't solve my problem. I've edited my question for clarity.

Comment: Could you show the expected output?

Comment: I wish I could. This is an assignment I am working on for class and the professor obviously hasn't posted the answer, so I'm not really sure what it should like. I just know that this distribution will be used to make a histogram.

Comment: This is the exact question given: Plot a histogram of the bootstrap distribution of the estimated slope
parameter for the following data.... the following data being the data above.

Comment: Were you assigned to use the `boot` package?

Comment: Sorry yes, we are supposed to use ```boot```. I'll edit that

Comment: Are you asking how to get the individual estimates back from your bootstrap object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost there... If we check the `boot` documentation with `?boot` and look for the part where it describes the return value (in R docs confusingly titled with just *Value*) we find this entry:

> t A matrix with sum(R) rows each of which is a bootstrap replicate of
>   the result of calling statistic.

Which means we only have to call

```
mybdone$t
```

To get:

```
           [,1]
 [1,] -2.470016
 [2,] -1.763517
 [3,] -1.856894
 [4,] -2.189789
 [5,] -1.276630
 [6,] -2.010069
 [7,] -2.002160
 [8,] -2.193305
 [9,] -1.840872
[10,] -3.810425
[11,] -2.585354
[12,] -2.836741
[13,] -1.869082
[14,] -3.209472
[15,] -1.041906
[16,] -2.167952
[17,] -2.807697
[18,] -1.445792
[19,] -3.355852
[20,] -1.756974
```

Which we can use for plotting or any computations. There is no shame in having to refer to `R`s excellent help system by calling `?name_of_a_function` to look up how the arguments or, as in this case, the return values are structured. I need to look stuff up this way all the time!

Comment: So are those values the bootstrap distribution of my slope? and therefore I can just use ```hist(mybdone$t)```?

Comment: Yes! Each of the 20 (because the `R` = number of replicates parameter to `boot` was 20) values in `mybdone$t` is a bootstrap replicate (result) of the desired statistic. Since we only wanted one parameter back from the boot procedure its a 20 x 1 matrix (but we could also have `b1` return `coef(lmout)[1:2], in which case  `mybdone$t` would be a 20 x 2 matrix. And `hist(mybdone$t)` is perfectly fine! As would be `plot(density((mybdone$t)))`